# React MUI Datagrid Top Center Alignment for Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I would like to set the alignment of the wrapped headers as top-center via `sx`:

```
const datagridSx = {
    '& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders': {
        height: 'unset !important',
        maxHeight: '168px !important',
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": {
        whiteSpace: "normal",
        lineHeight: "normal",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        verticalAlign: "top"
    },
};
```

but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example, like [a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/247cnw?file=/demo.tsx)?

Comment: Hi. My codesandbox example is here https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-brook-sddgsq?file=/demo.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `verticalAlign: "top"` on the `.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle` you can change the `alignItems` property on the `.MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer`.

So your `sx` would look something like this:

```js
const datagridSx = {
  ".MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitleContainer": {
    alignItems: "start",
  },
  "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaders": {
    height: "unset !important",
    maxHeight: "168px !important",
  },
  "& .MuiDataGrid-columnHeaderTitle": {
    whiteSpace: "normal",
    lineHeight: "normal",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
};
```